# JAVAFX Problem trying to play sound when clicking button

Tags: javafx, audio

I'm trying to make a sound of Windows play when the user clicks the button. The code is just below:

```
public class TestController extends Application {

    public String audio = getClass().getResource("src/Sounds/WindowsError.wav").toString();

     @FXML
     private Button playbt;

     @FXML
     void playtest(MouseEvent event)     
     {

         System.out.println("Clicked!");
        AudioClip clip = new AudioClip(audio);// 1
        clip.play(); // 2

     }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        try 

        {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/FXML/Test.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();

        } 

        catch (IOException e) 

        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The controller is properly configured to FXML. However, when I try to run the project, the following error occurs.

```
Exception in Application constructor java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class Controller.TestController
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$165(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Controller.TestController.<init>(TestController.java:17)
    ... 13 more Exception running application Controller.TestController
```

The files in my project are arranged as follows:

[image]

Does anyone know why this error occurs? The project hangs when opening due to the sound playback code.

Comment: You should not include source directory in the resource path. Use a path relative to the classpath root. Assuming the resource is properly deployed when running the app, `/Sounds/WindowsError.wav`. If this does not work, you may need to change the way you add the resources to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally solid on this, but I think the syntax of the getResource for the audio variable is in "relative address" form since it doesn't start with "/". In other words, it could be looking for a subfolder src in Controller package folder.

Maybe the following will help the system locate your audio resource:

```
public String audio = getClass().getResource("../Sounds/WindowsError.wav").toString();
```

Perhaps it would be good to move this line into the start() method, and run a System.out.println(audio) to inspect what you have at that point.

EDIT: just saw fabian's comment. Changing to the form using the classpath root as he suggests might be a better general practice than my suggestion to use a relative path.

Comment: `getClass().getResource` will use the same protocol to fetch the resource as was used to fetch the class.  If you access the class from the file system, then `..` will work as it is supported by the file system.  If you package the app as a jar file, then the [jar protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) will be used to access the resource.  The jar protocol does not support `..` in path values, and so fetching resources from the jar with `..` in the path will fail.

Comment: Just tested this out for myself, as I had never run across this problem before. And yes, the ".." doesn't work from within a jar. I guess I never made a jar that required this. I always located resources in a subfolder! So, yes, use the form of getResource that fabian recommends.